# Math behind Conway's Game of Life

Tags: cellular-automata

I'm an undergraduate student intending to double major in Computer Science and Pure Math, and I wish to do research on cellular automata in the future. My question is: what kind of mathematical basis do I need to understand automata like The Game of Life? How do people go about proving that certain formations are self replicating? How can we make complex mechanisms? Is it all combinatorics and sentential logic?

Comment: I'd say it's all about simulation. Check out some cellular automaton like Golly. If you want to check out some mechanisms, this is a good place to start http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Conway's Game of Life is certainly a reasonable thing to ask about -- but I think you need to put a bit more effort into asking a meaningful question. At present it seems unclear what you are asking, and also your question seems too broad and not sufficiently focused.

Comment: I agree with Stefan but would add that this question might be better received on [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/).  Even there, a more focused and specific question would be better.